# What type of List/Map should I use for categorizing data but maintaining the order?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, tree

I have the following data objects:

```
MyObject {
  priority (e.g. HIGH, LOW, ...)
  information
}
```

I need to save them in the correct order for iterating over it if necessary.

I also need to get only data with priority HIGH or LOW sometimes (also in correct order).

If I use a List (e.g. ArrayList) I would have to iterate over every single data-object to search for my priorities.

If I use `Map<Priority, List<Information>>` I would lose the order between information within two different priorities.

Sample data input:

1. LOW, "Hello1"
2. HIGH, "Hello2"
3. LOW, "World3"
4. HIGH, "World4"

Desired results:

```
printData() -> Hello1, Hello2, World3, World4
printLow() -> Hello1, World3
printHigh() -> Hello2, World4
```

What data structure would fulfill my requirements at the best? (Java)

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to implement? Should I have LinkedHashMap<Priority, MyObject> or what do you recommend?

Comment: You can have LinkedHashMap<Priority,ArrayList<Information>>

Comment: @DarshanLila that won't preserve the order between informations of different priorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If iterating over the list is really too slow, then maintain two parallel collections:

- a `List<Information>` to iterate over all the informations in order,
- and a `Map<Priority, List<Information>>` to iterate over the informations of a given priority.

I would only do that if I had a proven performance problem and I have proven that it was caused by the iteration over the list of all the informations. Otherwise, it's premature optimization that makes the code harder to maintain and make correct, especially if the collection is mutable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't have a performance problem and could clearly use a single list to iterate over. I just thought there might be a more convenient way to do so in Java ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use HashMap and a seperate list as below:

```
public enum Priority { .... };
Map<Priority, List<Information>> map = new HashMap<Priority, List<Information>>();
map.put(Priority.HIGH, new LinkedList<Information>());
map.put(Priority.MID, new LinkedList<Information>());
map.put(Priority.LOW, new LinkedList<Information>());
List<Information> infoOrderedList = new LinkedList<Information>();

public void putInfo(MyObject myobject) {
    List<Information> infoList = map.get(myObject.getPriority());
    infoList.add(myobject.getInformation());
    infoOrderedList.add(myobject.getInformation());
}

public void removeInfo(MyObject myobject) {
    List<Information> infoList = map.get(myObject.getPriority());
    infoList.remove(myobject.getInformation());
    infoOrderedList.remove(myobject.getInformation());
}
```

Comment: How would you implement `printData()` as the OP asked?

Comment: He can use infoOrderedList to print data while getLow/getHigh with o(1) on map?

Comment: So, basically, your answer is now the same as mine, except it insists on using LinkedHashMap and LinkedList although that doesn't have any advantage over any other Map or List.

Comment: No i am using HashMap and i dont know how many elements are going to be part of high/mid/low hence linked list.

Comment: Can you explain what advantage a LinkedList offers against an ArrayList in this case? (Hint: the answer is none. Iterating on a LinkedList is much slower than over an ArrayList).

Comment: I understand and there are always a tradeoff between space and time. So in arrayList, you have insertion overhead if it tries to expand the array's capacity (which is base of ArrayList) and when you have just one element it will create 10 array element..

Answer (score 1):

You may avoid explicit iteration using lambda and filtering on a List.
For instance if you want to get a list of high priority items just type:

```
List<MyObject> high = list.stream().filter(o -> o.priority == Priority.HIGH).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using an ArrayList you keep the sorting.
To improve performance you may use parallelStream() instead of stream()

Comment: This would work for sure. However, this is not efficient at all as this implementation does not avoid iterating through every object (it's just "hidden" in the lambda expression)

Comment: With lambda the operations can be executed in parallel.  With modern hardware you make more efficient use of the processor.  Up to you to see if it is worth implementing with more complex Collection/algorithm.

Comment: Quick question: Would parallelStream() maintain the order of the objects?

Comment: See official doc (search "ordering topic) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html.  Ordering should be kept but at the prize of lower performance than if ordering does not matter.